# ComboBox loses value after selectedvaluechange event fires

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, data-binding, combobox, datasource

Ok, so I searched on this, and the last post was dated 8 years ago, and was a different situation than what I am having.

I have a vb.net app - form opens, with 3 combo boxes.  each are data bound to separate tables.  1st one filters the second, which filters the third.
together, all 3 act as a filter to load a `DataSet`.

These are engineering charts for rv bill of materials.  I'm selecting model year, product series, then specific model. I use the `ComboBoxes` to collectively get my model index - I then load the `DataSet` based on that model index.

When I load the `DataSource` however, the model `ComboBox` and sometimes the model year go blank and their value nulls out.

I can confirm this by `Debug.Print` of their value which I assign to a class property to use as a sort of global variable.

Here's my code - hoping someone can see something I don't as to why they blank out.

This is a front to an access database. You will see I now have a button to do the load, where I used to trigger off of the last combo index change event, but I get the same result.

```
 'define selected chart      
 Dim schart As New Chart
 Private Sub frmchartentry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Read the model year table and look for default value.
    'Then use that value to filter the series combobox.

    Call loaddata()
    Call getyear()

    'cmbSeries.Text = ""
    'cmbModel.Text = ""
    TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
    schart.Category = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
    Debug.Print(schart.Category)

End Sub
Private Sub loaddata()

    Me.TblModelYearTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsModelYear.tblModelYear)
    Me.TblProductListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsSeries.tblProductList)
    Me.TblModelListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsModels.tblModelList)
    Me.TblItemMasterTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsItemMaster.tblItemMaster)
    'Me.TblChartUsageTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsChartEntry.tblChartUsage)

End Sub
Private Sub getyear()

    'Load default year based on boolean field in database
    Dim myear As String = ""

    For i = 0 To DsModelYear.tblModelYear.Rows.Count - 1

        If DsModelYear.tblModelYear.Rows(i)("Default").ToString = True Then
            myear = DsModelYear.tblModelYear.Rows(i)("ModelYear").ToString
            cmbYear.SelectedValue = myear
            schart.Year = myear
            Debug.Print(schart.Year)
            TblProductListBindingSource.Filter = "ModelYear = " & schart.Year
        End If

    Next

End Sub
Private Sub cmbSeries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbSeries.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Filter Model List based on Series chosen
    schart.Series = cmbSeries.SelectedValue
    Debug.Print(schart.Series)
    TblModelListBindingSource.Filter = "ModelYear = " & schart.Year & " And SeriesID like '" & schart.Series & "'"

End Sub

Private Sub cmbModel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbModel.SelectedIndexChanged

    schart.Model = cmbModel.SelectedValue
    Debug.Print(schart.Model)
    'Call gridfilter()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadGrid()

    'load dataset for year, series, and model selected - then filter for category selection
    'Selecting model triggers dataset to fill - increases performance this way.

    'Me.TblChartUsageTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = True
    Me.TblChartUsageTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsChartEntry.tblChartUsage)
    'TblChartUsageBindingSource.Filter = "ModelIndex = '" & schart.Model & "'" & " And Category = '" & schart.Category & "'"

End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selected

    schart.Category = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
    Debug.Print(schart.Category)
    Call gridfilter()

    'TblChartUsageBindingSource.Filter = "Category like '" & TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text & "'"
    'TblChartUsageBindingSource.Filter = "Category like '" & TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name & "'"

End Sub

Private Sub gridfilter()

    Debug.Print(schart.Year)
    Debug.Print(schart.Series)
    Debug.Print(schart.Category)
    Debug.Print(schart.Model)

    Dim fltr As String = ""
    Dim fcat As String
    Dim ftag As String = "*"

    If schart.Category = "Electrical 12v" Then
        fcat = "Electrical"
        ftag = "12V"
        fltr = "ModelIndex = '" & schart.Model & "'" & " And Category = '" & fcat & "'" & " And Tag = '" & ftag & "'"
    ElseIf schart.Category = "Electrical 120v" Then
        fcat = "Electrical"
        ftag = "120V"
        fltr = "ModelIndex = '" & schart.Model & "'" & " And Category = '" & fcat & "'" & " And Tag = '" & ftag & "'"
    Else fcat = schart.Category
        fltr = "ModelIndex = '" & schart.Model & "'" & " And Category = '" & fcat & "'"
    End If
    Debug.Print(fltr)

    TblChartUsageBindingSource.Filter = fltr

End Sub

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Call LoadGrid()
    Call gridfilter()

End Sub

'Edited to make code more readable
```

Comment: You've not actually shown the code for the `SelectedValueChanged` method.

Comment: yes, sorry, I'm using the selected index event. When the form loads, the year combobox is automatically selecting the current model year.  I have a Boolean field "default" so that it can be configured.  That selection filters the series list, when you select the series, that filters which models show in the models list.  the button_click event then grabs that info and does the dataset fill function.  when the user selects a tab from the tab control, that filters the datagrid based on the category(tab) selected.  however when the table loads - the combos go blank.